# How to add a reusable view without loading from xib in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Very new to Swift here, thanks for being patient!

Say I want to write a reusable scroll view called `ProfileView` like so (question is highlighted below):

```
import UIKit

class ProfileView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var profileView: UIScrollView!
    var profile: Profile!    // Profile is a custom class
                             // It contains user's profile, name, etc

    init (frame: CGRect, profile: Profile) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        profileScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: frame)
        self.profile = profile
        loadView()
    }

    func loadView() {
        profileScrollView.delegate = self

        // Then go ahead and display user's profile info such as
        // their names and profile pictures etc
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("\(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
    }
}
```

You might've noticed, `ProfileView` inherits from `UIScrollViewDelegate` as well, because I want to do some animation when users scroll. The question is:

**How do I add the scroll view to an existing view?**

I've tried this in my `ViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet var container: UIView!    // "container" is all of "Safe Area"
var profile = <Some object that's not nil>

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    container.addSubview(ProfileView(frame: container.frame, profile: profile))
    print("\(container.subviews.debugDescription)")
}
```

But the scroll view is not shown and the "print" statement prints:

```
[
 <_UILayoutGuide:      0x7fca15107cf0; frame = (0 0; 0 0);     hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c00003a1c0>>,
 <_UILayoutGuide:      0x7fca1510eb60; frame = (0 0; 0 0);     hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c000037260>>,
 <TestApp.ProfileView: 0x7fca151031e0; frame = (0 0; 414 736); layer = <CALayer: 0x60c000036fc0>>
]
```

Comment: Change `frame: container.frame` to `frame: container.bounds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "But the scroll view is not shown". And that is easy to understand; it's because you never show it.

Look at your `ProfileView` class code. It declares a `profileScrollView` which is a scroll view, and gives it a frame, and gives it a delegate, but it never puts that scroll view into the interface. You add the ProfileView itself to the interface, but you never add the ProfileView's `profileScrollView` to the interface.

Somewhere, somehow, you would need to tell some view that *is* in the interface to `addSubview(profileScrollView)`. But you never do.